# Open files in NetBeans 8.0.2 are kept in the project file thus making it dirty in GIT

Tags: c++, netbeans, project

I've been using NetBeans for the last couple of years and only recently upgraded to 8.0.2. It seems that the new project file tracks which files are open in the project workspace (C++) and thus the project file appears as modified whenever I open Netbeans, although I haven't changed anything. Is there a setting to disable this?

Comment: Which file are you seeing as modified? Are you using git from the command-line or the menus built-in to Netbeans?

Comment: @WillShackleford The modified file is private.xml in nbproject folder. I guess the whole private folder should be out of GIT. I am using the NetBeans builtin menus.

Comment: I am not sure whether you needed the git instructions.  I added it as an answer just in case. For Java projects it seems to automatically ignore the private directory, so that may be a bug. All my old projects already had the private directory in gitignore but the new one I created seems to have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Create a file named ".gitignore" in the top-level directory, if it does not
already exist.

Add the line:

```
nbproject/private/
```

To do this with Netbeans:
Window -> Files, Select the Directory and right-click for Pop-up.
New -> Other ... -> Empty File.
Name the file ".gitignore"

When you do diffs and commits etc. it should ignore the private files that might have changed.